Python Not beeing able to scrape details of a Listing
I have to scrape some details such as Listings link and the id of the merchant. Without having a Browser open/visible.
Example link: https://www.trendyol.com/sr?q=telefon&qt=telefon&st=telefon&os=1 There are 24 listings on each page. I need to scrape the Link of each listing AND the merchantID which is already inside the listing link
https://www.trendyol.com/apple/iphone-11-128-gb-beyaz-cep-telefonu-aksesuarsiz-kutu-apple-turkiye-garantili-p-64074794?boutiqueId=632934&merchantId=968
This is a Listing link and as you can see, the MerchantID is visible inside the link at the very end (968)
But somehow my code is not scraping any link&Merchant at all. No error message printed. Just the 0 Results.
Then I tried to use selenium (with an open/visible browser window) and it worked. But the Same Code with the "Headless" mode did not work. Also with just Requests and BS4 is not working too.
This is the Code that I used:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import datetime
import os
import time

# Dictionary for mapping sst values to their respective names
sst_mapping = {
    'SCORE': 'Score',
    'PRICE_BY_ASC': 'Ascending Price',
    'PRICE_BY_DESC': 'Descending Price',
    'BEST_SELLER': 'Best Seller',
    'MOST_FAVOURITE': 'Favourites',
    'MOST_RECENT': 'Recent',
    'MOST_RATED': 'Most Ratings'
}

def scrape_trendyol(link, existing_merchants):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Check if we reached the end page
    if response.url == "https://www.trendyol.com/sr":
        return [], set(), True

    products = []
    new_merchants = set()

    for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='p-card-chldrn-cntnr card-border'):
        link_tag = item.find('a', href=True)
        if link_tag:
            product_link = "https://www.trendyol.com" + link_tag['href']
            merchant_id_match = re.search(r'merchantId=(\d+)', product_link)

            if merchant_id_match:
                merchant_id = merchant_id_match.group(1)
                if merchant_id not in existing_merchants and merchant_id not in new_merchants:
                    products.append((product_link, merchant_id))
                    new_merchants.add(merchant_id)

    return products, new_merchants, False

def save_to_txt(products, base_filename):
    links_filename = base_filename + ".txt"
    merchants_filename = base_filename + "_merchantIDs.txt"

    with open(links_filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as links_file, \
         open(merchants_filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as merchants_file:
        for product_link, merchant_id in products:
            links_file.write(product_link + '\n')
            merchants_file.write(merchant_id + '\n')

def append_new_merchants(filename, new_merchants):
    with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for merchant_id in new_merchants:
            f.write(merchant_id + '\n')

def read_links_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]

def read_existing_merchants(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        return set()
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return set(line.strip() for line in f if line.strip())

def get_filename_from_link(link):
    query_params = dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^\&]+)', link))
    query = query_params.get('q', 'Unknown').capitalize()
    sst = query_params.get('sst', 'Unknown')
    sst_name = sst_mapping.get(sst, 'Unknown')
    date_time_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y_%H.%M.%S")
    return f"{date_time_str}_{query}_{sst_name}"

def get_paginated_link(base_link, page_number):
    return f"{base_link}&pi={page_number}"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    base_links = read_links_from_file('Linkler.txt')
    existing_merchants = read_existing_merchants('merchantIDs.txt')
    initial_merchant_count = len(existing_merchants)
    total_new_merchants = 0

    for base_link in base_links:
        page_number = 1
        all_products = []
        all_new_merchants = set()
        while page_number <= 208:
            url = get_paginated_link(base_link, page_number)
            products, new_merchants, end_reached = scrape_trendyol(url, existing_merchants)
            if end_reached:
                break
            all_products.extend(products)
            all_new_merchants.update(new_merchants)
            existing_merchants.update(new_merchants)
            total_new_merchants += len(new_merchants)
            print(f"{len(products)} Listing scraped: {url}")
            page_number += 1

        if all_products:
            base_filename = get_filename_from_link(base_link)
            save_to_txt(all_products, base_filename)
            append_new_merchants('merchantIDs.txt', all_new_merchants)
            print(f"All listings added here: '{base_filename}.txt'")
            print(f"All merchantIDs added here: '{base_filename}_merchantIDs.txt'")

    final_merchant_count = len(existing_merchants)
    print(f"\nNew added merchantsı: {total_new_merchants}")
    print(f"Total Merchant İD: {final_merchant_count}")

    time.sleep(5)    


How can I make it Scrape the desired Information, without an open Browser like Selenium.
I tried to locate the Information diffrently.
I tried to use the code as "Headless" Selenium.
